# Html Agility Pack: how to scrape <tr> text?

Tags: html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

```
<tr id='tr1' align='center' border=0 class='headerclass'>
  Example text
  <tr id='tr11' align='center' border=0 bgColor='99ccff'> 
    <td id='td1' class='headerclass'>Example Header 1 </td>
    <td id='td2' class='headerclass'>Example Header 2 </td>
    <td id='td3' class='headerclass'>Example Header 3 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='tr12' align='center"'bgColor='white'>
    <td id='v1' class='colclass'>value 1</td>
    <td id='v2' class='colclass'>value 2</td>
    <td id='v3' class='colclass'>value 3</td>
  </tr>
</tr>
```

Above is the HTML example that I wanted to scrape. I want to get *Example text* which is in `<tr></tr>`. I tried to use *InnerText* (code as shown below) but it returns me all the text in `<td></td>` as well which is not what I want. I would like to get *Example text* only.

```
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr").Where(x => x.Attributes["id"] != null && x.Attributes["id"].Value.Contains("tr1"));
foreach (var htmlNode in nodes)
{
   Console.WriteLine(htmlNode.InnerText);
}
```

Output:

```
Example text
Example Header 1
Example Header 2
Example Header 3 
value 1
value 2
value 3
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that's valid HTML (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element), so any HTML parser's response to it is likely to be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it something like this :

```
var text = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr")
               .First(p => p.Attributes["id"] != null &&   
               p.Attributes["id"].Value.Contains("tr1")).ChildNodes[0].InnerText.Trim();
```

The output is :

```
Example text
```